# No module named flask in virtualenv although installed

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I want to use Flask to develop a website but I am having already problems getting a simple demo app running.

I followed the complete installation tutorial of [the flask website](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/)
Means:

- I created a project directory.
- Inside this directory I created my virtualenv folder like described in the tutorial.
- I started the virtual environment using *. venv/bin/activate*
- I installed flask inside the virtualenv by *pip install Flask*

If I now open the python console via *python* (while running venv) and I try
*from flask import Flask* I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: No module named 'flask'

Also running a simple Hello World app like the following gives the same error.
If I try to install flask again in venv, the following is shown in the console:
[image]

```
from flask import Flask
application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def hello():
    return "hello world"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

For completeness: I already searched a lot on SO and google but could not find the same problem. Although I found a few related all of them had the problem that the one asking either forgot installing flask inside venv or forgot activating venv etc.
Also if I type which python it points correctly to the folder bin/python inside my venv folder.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I solved the issue: If I use python3 instead of python to execute my program or to open python console everything works as expected.
Still, this is weird, because (inside venv) doing *which python3* points to the python3 file inside the bin folder of my venv, but *which python* points to a symbolic link inside the same folder, which points again to exactly the same python3 file.